# How to connect to an encrypted SQLite database?

Tags: java, sqlite

I created an SQLite database using "DB Browser for SQLite" and encrypted it using SQLCipher 3, but when I execute my code the database is unreadable. I removed the encryption and it works.

How can I connect to an encrypted SQLite database? I already added the SQLCipher jar to my build path > library.

> ERROR :opening db: 'src/database/cryptedDB.db?key=kilikilikoinkoin' : File, directory, or volume name syntax is incorrect

Code:

```
public class DBmanager {
    
    Connection connection;
    String database= "jdbc:sqlite:src/database/cryptedDB.db";
    private String encryptionKey = "kilikilikoinkoin";
    
    public DBmanager() {
        
    }
    
    public boolean Connect() throws SQLException {
        try {
            String url = database + "?key=" + encryptionKey;

             // Establish the connection with the modified URL
             Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            if (connection != null && !connection.isClosed()) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return false;
        
    }
}
```

Changing URL from  `?key=` to `?pragma_key=` is not working. Eclipse shows error in `sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery()` and the correction is to "build path" even though I already added SQLCipher.

```
SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(); // Load SQLCipher native libraries
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(database, passphrase, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
long nativeConnectionPtr =sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT sqlite3_handle_v2('main');",null).getLong(0);
// Wrap the native connection in a java.sql.Connection object using SQLite JDBC driver
SQLiteConfig config = new SQLiteConfig();
config.setSharedCache(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the JDBC library

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.willena</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.41.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then Create the connection

```
Connection connection =
                 DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:file:cryptedDB.db?cipher=sqlcipher&key=kilikilikoinkoin&legacy=3")
```

Also, make sure "file" part in the JDBC connection string.